# unable to read contents of file systems

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I used to own a windows-based laptop but I wanted to partition the disk for ubuntu installation. After two weeks of debugging, defragmentation and windows settings, I was still unable to partition the disk. Therefore I backup up and remove the whole windows system for re-partitioning as a whole. I hope it would solve the problem.

Yet in the middle of my ubuntu installation, I tried a few settings then my disk could not response to partition again. Currently my laptop has no operating windows system. Only CD booted ubuntu (try ubuntu option) is available.

In GParted Partition Editor, there is a warning sign on that disk which stated -

> Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of of software packages is required for ntfs file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.

Is there any way to save the disk and complete the partition? Please tell me if it is a duplicate. I am already exhausted from encountering endless issues these weeks.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It seems like your Ubuntu CD does not have *ntfs* support. You can (temporarily) install the two needed packages by running `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs` in a shell in the live Ubuntu environment and launch GParted again.

Comment: It returned with "... Reading state information... Done\\ E: Unable to locate package ntfsprogs" Will that be a problem?

Comment: I have typed in the command to install the two packages. The returned message suggests ntfsprogs could not be installed somehow. GParted still cannot read the disk right now

Comment: Then ntfsprogs is not supported for your distro and you should use ntfs-3g only. It's weird, though, as all Ubuntu versions I used (12.04+) supported NTFS out of the box.

Comment: The CD is in version 14.04 and it was used by my friend a year ago. Is there any other way to recover my disk?

Comment: I don't know how old that laptop is, but given that you can't partition your drive, it's either dead or you need to rewrite the MBR/GPT using GParted.

Comment: Then format to NTFS when installing the OS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41181/discussion-between-simon-and-gianttree).

Answer (score 1):

Today, I was looking at this question and it's comments. I found out that removing *ntfs-3g* from a live USB of Ubuntu 16.4 allowed me to access my 500gb Windows drive which was not working before with gparted while it was installed. I don't know what fixed it, but it's now working fine. 
Sorry if I missed anything, this is my first post here.